# Vertical thumbstrip to the left showing thumbs for ALL galleries

Tags: highslide

I have three galleries with highslide, with ten pictures each that have a Vertical thumbstrip to the left. The problem is that each gallery show ALL 30 thumbnails and I would like to see only the 10 thumbnails related to each gallery.

How can I control this?

Comment: A link to your site would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this Highslide FAQ item: [How do I put more than one gallery in the same page?](http://www.highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=4682)